# Use of impression in AdRotator

Tags: asp.net

How can I use impression tag which is within advertisement
How it affects for different images...

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps you -

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/AdRotator_VT.aspx